# Problem using NonlinearModelFit to 2 coupled differential equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, fitting, nonlinear

I am trying to find the parameters of a set of differential equations given experimental data. Before I tackled my set of 12 equations, I tried to solve a simpler and similar 2 equation system but have not been able to manage.

First I created a system and solved it, summed the outputs{x,y} and then added noise.

```
Clear[f, g, x, y, model]
sol = NDSolve[{y''[t] == 5*x[t] - y[t], x''[t] == 2*y[t] - 10*x[t], 
y[0] == 3, y'[0] == 0, x[0] == 3, x'[0] == 5}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 
5}];

tvals = Range[0, 5, 0.1];

data = Transpose[{tvals, 
Flatten[Evaluate[x[tvals] /. sol] + Evaluate[y[tvals] /. sol]] + 
RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, Length[tvals]]}];

Show[Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol] + Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 5}, 
PlotStyle -> Green], ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]]
```

Next, I try to fit a curve  and find the parameters of the original differential equations {5,-1,2,-10}. Here is my attempt:

```
model[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, c_?NumberQ, 
d_?NumberQ] := (model[a, b, c, d] = 
First[sol2 = 
NDSolve[{f''[t] == a*g[t] - b*f[t], g''[t] == c*f[t] - d*g[t], 
f[0] == 3, f'[0] == 0, g[0] == 3, g'[0] == 5}, 
g + f, {t, 0, 5}]])


nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, 
Evaluate[model[a, b, c, d][t] /. sol2], {a, b, c, d}, t];

Show[Plot[nlm[t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All], ListPlot[data]]
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

All I get is error messages an I am unsure of what to do.

Comment: Your `model` does not depend on `a,b,c,d`...

Comment: Also, as long as you have the `_?NumberQ` pattern, the `Evaluate` in `NonlinearModelFit` won't do anything, because `a,b,c,d` won't be numbers when `Evaluate` is evoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I assume that the variables `{a, b, c, d}` are given in the differential equations model. (Not as initial values as in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/179641/34008).)

The idea is to make set of functions to fit with different parameters and pick the ones that give the best fit.

Redefine the `model`:

```
Clear[model]
model[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, c_?NumberQ, d_?NumberQ] := 
  First[sol2 = 
    NDSolve[{f''[t] == b*g[t] - a *f[t], g''[t] == c*f[t] - d*g[t], 
      f[0] == 3, f'[0] == 0, g[0] == 3, g'[0] == 5}, {f, g}, {t, 0, 
      5}]];

model[1, 2, 3, 2]
```

Construct a (reasonable) set of functions:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 bFuncs = 
   Association[
    Flatten[Table[{a, b, c, d} -> model[a, b, c, d], {a, 0, 6, 1}, {b, 0, 10, 1}, {c, 0, 6, 1}, {d, 8, 12, 1}]]];
 ]
(* {3.31016, Null} *(

Length[bFuncs]

(* 2695 *)
```

Compute the fit for all functions in the set:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 fitErrRes =
   Table[(
     fit = Fit[data, Through[Values[bFuncs[[i]]][t]], t];
     errs = Map[(fit /. t -> #[[1]]) - #[[2]] &, data];
     Keys[bFuncs][[i]] -> Norm[errs, \[Infinity]]), {i, 1, 
     Length[bFuncs]}];
 ]

(* {5.37995, Null} *)
```

Pick the bet fit:

```
Through[{Min, Max, Mean, StandardDeviation}[
  Values[fitErrRes]]]

(* {0.538426, 23.9603, 15.4338, 4.54161} *)

sInd = 
 Flatten[Position[Values[fitErrRes], Min[Values[fitErrRes]]]][[1]]

(* 573 *)

Keys[bFuncs][[sInd]]

(* {1, 5, 2, 10} *)
```

Plot

```
Show[{ListPlot[data], 
  Plot[Evaluate[Total[Through[Values[bFuncs[[sInd]]][t]]]], {t, 
    Min[data[[All, 1]]], Max[data[[All, 1]]]}]}]
```

[image]

You can extend and/or narrow the search by changing the set search functions `bFuncs`.

Comment: Thanks all. A mistake on my behalf. The {a,b,c,d} were meant to be the coefficients in the DEs but I was playing around with the code and forgot to change the numbers back to letters before I copied and pasted the code.

Comment: @VincenzoPratley It is a good question. If your code was more streamlined I assume it would have got more attention. Please make the corresponding clarifications...

Comment: edits made. I have only been using Mathematica for about 2 weeks and I am also a relative beginner at programming.

Comment: @VincenzoPratley Ok, thank you for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[f, g, x, y, model]
sol = NDSolve[{y''[t] == 5*x[t] - y[t], x''[t] == 2*y[t] - 10*x[t], 
    y[0] == 3, y'[0] == 0, x[0] == 3, x'[0] == 5}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 5}];

tvals = Range[0, 5, 0.1];

data = Transpose[{tvals, 
    Flatten[Evaluate[x[tvals] /. sol] + Evaluate[y[tvals] /. sol]] + 
     RandomReal[{-0.5, 0.5}, Length[tvals]]}];

Show[Plot[Evaluate[y[t] /. sol] + Evaluate[x[t] /. sol], {t, 0, 5}, 
  PlotStyle -> Green], ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]]
model[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, c_?NumberQ, d_?NumberQ] := 
 Module[{y, t}, 
   First[y /. 
     NDSolve[{f''[t] == 5*g[t] - f[t], g''[t] == 2*f[t] - 10*g[t], 
       f[0] == a, f'[0] == b, g[0] == c, g'[0] == d, 
       y[t] == f[t] + g[t], y[0] == a + c}, {g, f, y}, {t, 0, 5}]]] //
   Quiet


nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data, model[a, b, c, d][t], {a, b, c, d}, 
    t]; // Quiet

Show[Plot[nlm[t], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> All], ListPlot[data]]
nlm["ParameterTable"]
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: Good (+1). Are was thinking that `{a,b,c,d}` are coefficients in the differential equations, not in the initial values.