# Nonlinearfit with incomplete data

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

Suppose I have an ODE model and some incomplete time series data

```
data = {{0,1},{5,6.2},{14,18.4},{28,57.3},{90,105.2},{180,98}}
```

My question, can I still use NonlinearModelFit[data,model,...] even though the data set is missing the values for $y$.

Here is a toy problem:

```
T = 180;
soln = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == 
r1 x[t] (1 - (x[t] + y[t])/k1), 
y'[t] == r2 y[t] (1 - (x[t] + y[t])/k2), x[0] == y[0] == 1}, {x,y}, {t, T},{r1, k1, r2, k2}];

data = {{0, 1.}, {7, 3.85818}, {14, 13.498}, {28, 65.3818}, {90, 
  90.4873}, {180, 90.4875}};
```

Comment: This question seems to be a duplicate of ["Problem using NonlinearModelFit to 2 coupled differential equations"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/179631/34008).

Comment: You could try `NonlinearModelFit[data, 
 X = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == r1 x[t] (1 - (x[t] + y[t])/k1), 
    y'[t] == r2 y[t] (1 - (x[t] + y[t])/k2), x[0] == y[0] == 1}, 
   x, {t, T}, {r1, k1, r2, k2}];
 X[r1, k1, r2, k2][t], {r1, k1, r2, k2}, t ]`. The idea is to only use the x-part of the NDSolve-solution. Unfortunately evaluation takes ~infinite time... Are there additional constraints for the parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The examplary solution idea:

```
data = Table[{t, Exp[-t]}, {t, Sort[RandomReal[{0, 5}, 10]]}];(*{t,x}*)
```

Set of two coupled ode, only x[t] is used to estimate the unknown parameter a:

```
mod = NonlinearModelFit[data,
X =ParametricNDSolveValue[ {x'[t] == a x[t] z[t] , x[0] == 1,z'[t] == 0, z[0] == 1}, x, {t, 0, 5}, a]  ;
X[a][t], {a} , t ] ;
mod["BestFitParameters"]
(*{a -> -1.} *)
```